# I can't import local packages in my go project

Tags: windows, visual-studio, go, goland, golangci-lint

folder structure:

```
- myproject
  - resolver
    - resolver.go
  - main.go
```

```
go mod init github.com/kaleabbyh/foodrecipie
```

**resolver.go:**

```golang
package resolvers

import "fmt"

func resolverfunc(){
    fmt.Println("resolvers are running")
}
```

**main.go:**

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/kaleabbyh/foodrecipie/resolvers"
)

func main(){
    resolvers.resolverfunc()
    fmt.Println("main is running")
}
```

I try to do just like the above details but it returns me

> no required module provides package "github.com/kaleabbyh/foodrecipie/resolvers"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you used `package resolvers`, the name of that package's directory is `resolver`, therefore the import path for that package (regardless of its name) is not `"github.com/kaleabbyh/foodrecipie/resolvers"` but instead `"github.com/kaleabbyh/foodrecipie/resolver"`.

Note also that, to be able to call functions in imported packages those functions need to be **exported** (i.e. they MUST start with an upper case letter). In other words; `resolvers.resolverfunc()` is not gonna work (even if you manage to fix the import issue) because `resolverfunc` is **unexported** (i.e. it starts with a lower case letter). See: https://go.dev/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers

Comment: mkopriva, you are right.

using small letter for the first letter of the function's name is the problem.

Solved